# Using createLink to share with specific users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to create a link to share a document with `createLink` from Microsoft Graph for specific users `without using an invite` but it is creating a link with `Anyone with the link can edit this document` permission.

I'm calling this endpoint:

```
POST /me/drive/items/{itemId}/createLink
```

With this request body:

```
{
  "type": "edit",
  "scope": "anonymous"
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `"type": "edit"` What else would you expect?

Comment: is there any request param to create link for specific user ?

Comment: I don't know.  Check the documentation for the request body.

Comment: I have gone through the documentation  [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createlink) but there is nothing much.

Comment: Ah, thought the edit was the problem.... you can't do that in the website, so I doubt that's a possibility.

Comment: This is available on OneDrive UI which I am trying to achieve with Microsoft Graph API.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `createLink` for sharing with a specific person, you need to use the `invite` endpoint for that.

The call you're making is responding exactly how you've asked it to and generating a link (`createLink`) that anyone (`anonymous`) can access.

If you don't want to send a physical invitation, you can tell OneDrive this by setting the `sendInvitation` property to `false`:

```http
POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/invite
Content-type: application/json

{
  "requireSignIn": true,
  "sendInvitation": false,
  "roles": [ "write", "read"],
  "recipients": [
    {
      "email": "someone@contoso.org"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The invite api does not return the share url. How do I get that?

Comment: The URL is the `webUrl` property of the `DriveItem` you shared.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522229/using-microsofts-secure-external-sharing-via-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_invite 
You can share the file with specific user by adding user's in
"recipients":[{"@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.driveRecipient"}]
parameter. You can set sendInvitation parameter like "sendInvitation":false to avoid sending the invitation mail.

Comment: I already mentioned that I want to do it without using invite endpoint.